# Opendialog box > Select txt file > display contents into a text box

Tags: vb.net

Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question. But i'm trying to open a txt file using a button (open dialog). Then display the results of the the text file into a textbox (that I can edit the values) after that I hit another button called save that writes to the text file.

Is this possible?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.IO
Imports System


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        Dim strFileName As String

        fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
        fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        fd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        fd.FilterIndex = 2
        fd.RestoreDirectory = True

        If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            strFileName = fd.FileName
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

[My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xrdx.png)

Comment: In this link there is all you need to read and understand https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Reading the file

When `fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK`, you also need to actually read the file and load its contents into your textbox. @steve provided a link that shows the reading part; load into textbox

2. TextBox1_TextChanged()

Not sure what you need to do when this is triggered

3. If you need to save back to the same file, it will be through Button2_Click?

@steve provided a link that shows the how to; read from textbox.

Do read every linked item on that page; it's worthwhile. You'll have information that you'll need and use several dozens of times in the future.